# just 1st record is not displaying is drowpdown. but other is displaying . code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

[add_library form ]

```
<select   name="employee_id" class="form-control">
                                <option  value="">Select Employee.....</option
                                <?php
                                if (!empty($employee_info) && is_array($employee_info)){
                                    foreach ($employee_info as $emp_info) {
                                        // blow option of compare db id and  select option value ?>
                                        <option  <?php echo ($emp_info->employee_id==$library_info->employee_id  ) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>

                                        value="<?php echo $emp_info->employee_id; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $emp_info->first_name . ' ' . $emp_info->last_name ?>
                                    </option>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
```

here is screen shot of front end. Am new in developing. thanks for help in advance . [this is the pic of front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62jeH.png)

Comment: show the code, we are not magicians who can generate code by image.

Comment: add _library.php             if (!empty($employee_info) && is_array($employee_info)){
                                foreach ($employee_info as $emp_info) {
                                    // blow option of compare db id and  select option value ?>
                                    <option  <?php echo ($emp_info->employee_id==$library_info->employee_id  ) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>

                                    value="<?php echo $emp_info->employee_id; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $emp_info->first_name . ' ' . $emp_info->last_name ?>
     </option> <?php

Comment: you should add this code in your question by clicking on edit button.

Comment: function in Controller    $this->library_model->_table_name = 'tbl_employee';
        $this->library_model->_order_by = 'employee_id';
        $data['employee_info'] = $this->library_model->get();

Comment: am unable to add code in question :(

Comment: You can [edit] your own question.

Comment: am adding but error is appearing your code in not in proper format. :(

Comment: @ufumedia Don't put big lots of code in comments re edit you question by clicking on your edit button below tags.

Comment: There is no opening "<option>" tag for the first name. Suspect something is awry for your for (or while) loop.

Comment: ok thanks @jeo am checking

Comment: still not working

Comment: @Joe i have added code now tell me please whats wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how you have this set up, because I wouldn't do it this way. But try this:

```
<select name="employee_id" class="form_control">
    <option value="">Select Employee...</option>
    <?php
    if (!empty($employee_info)) { // Left out the is_array. You can check one or the other. empty only checks arrays. Can include it to be thorough
        foreach ($employee_info AS $ei) {
            echo '<option value="' . $ei->employee_id . '"';
            echo ($ei->employee_id == $library_info->employee_id) ? ' SELECTED ' : '' . '>';
            echo $ei->first_name . ' ' . $ei->last_name;
            echo '</option>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

It may take a little tweaking.

Comment: thanks @jeo you are superb

Comment: @ufumedia As many times as I had to edit that answer to correct typos, I'm glad you were able to make something sensible out of it.